# call Oracle Stored Procedure using Hibernate JPA 2.1 with IN parameter list and out Cursor

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to call a stored procedure with a set of ids in parameter and expecting to return a set of Object results.

I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa with an ORacle DB 12c and corresponding JDBC driver.

Oracle PL SQL:

```
create or replace type input_customer_ids is table of VARCHAR2(100);

create or replace procedure stored_p
    (customer_ids IN input_customer_ids,prc OUT sys_refcursor )as
       begin
       open
       prc for SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE 
       where customer_id IN (select * from table(customer_ids));
end;
```

Then in java side :

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
.
.
public List<ClientAlertEntity> getAllClientAlertsList(List<String> customerIds) {
        StoredProcedureQuery findAllproc =
                em.createStoredProcedureQuery("STORED_P",ClientAlertEntity.class);
        findAllproc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("customer_ids", ArrayList.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        findAllproc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("prc", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
        findAllproc.setParameter("customer_ids", customerIds);
        findAllproc.execute();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<ClientAlertEntity> results = (List<ClientAlertEntity>)findAllproc.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
```

I got : wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STORED_P'

```
[WARN ] 2018-05-28 12:25:23.790 [http-nio-8000-exec-2] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
[ERROR] 2018-05-28 12:25:23.790 [http-nio-8000-exec-2] SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STORED_P'
ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

[ERROR] 2018-05-28 12:25:23.801 [http-nio-8000-exec-2] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STORED_P'
ORA-06550: Ligne 1, colonne 7 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.. has anybody got the solution?

Comment: unfortunately not, i had to use plain old JDBC...